# Dojo 1.9: Node.js relative path issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo

I am having trouble using the Dojo Toolkit with NodeJS when it comes to requiring a relative standard node.js file:

I have the following directory

```
node-stuff
  start-server.js
  source
    dojo
    app-client
    app-common
    app-server
      lib
        http-server.js
      routes
        index.js
      server-config.js
      server.js
```

I use the start-server.js file to bootstrap the dojo toolkit:

```
dojoConfig = require('./source/app-server/server-config');
require("./source/dojo/dojo.js");
```

This loads the server configuration file that contains the dojoConfig information

```
module.exports = {
    baseUrl: 'source/',
    async: true,
    packages: [
        {
            name: 'dojo',
            location: 'dojo'
        },
        {
            name: 'app-server',
            location: 'app-server'
        },
        {
            name: 'app-client',
            location: 'app-client'
        },
        {
            name: 'app-common',
            location: 'app-common'
        }
    ],
    deps: [
        "source/app-server/server.js"
    ]
};
```

Inside of my http-server.js file, I am trying to use the following node require:

```
define([
  "dojo/node!express", //works OK
  "dojo/node!path", //works OK
  "app-common/roots", //works OK
  "dojo/node!../routes/index"] //this last one has the following error message
```

The error message produced

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" start-server.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'source\app-server\routes\index'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at source/dojo/node.js:41:15
    at Object.load (source/dojo/node.js:46:6)
    at injectPlugin (C:\Users\james_000\RubymineProjects\node-stuff\source\dojo\dojo.js:1321:13)
    at C:\Users\james_000\RubymineProjects\node-stuff\source\dojo\dojo.js:1136:6
    at forEach (C:\Users\james_000\RubymineProjects\node-stuff\source\dojo\dojo.js:93:6)
    at resolvePluginLoadQ (C:\Users\james_000\RubymineProjects\node-stuff\source\dojo\dojo.js:1129:4)
```

I have tried getting the latest version of node off of the Dojo Github. That changed the error line from

```
Cannot find module 'source\app-server\routes\index'
```

to

```
Cannot find module 'app-server\routes\index'
```

Is this a bug here, or am I doing something wrong?

I'm wondering if the problem is that the dojo/node! is always coercing the path to be source/app-server/routes/index instead of ./source/app-server/routes/index. If I put the source/app-server/routes folder in the node_modules folder, then it works fine. It doesn't seem to like relative file paths that are not inside of that folder.

EDIT: I tested the above, and it was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/16414#comment:16 which was fixed in Dojo 1.9.1.

EDIT: Also, your `baseUrl` needs to be an absolute path to the directory.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't seem to work. I upgraded to the latest version of Dojo, and I still get the error. It is grabbing the right file path (relative to the project directory) but it still isn't recognizing that it is there, even though it is. (I can use an absolute path to get at it, but I'm trying to avoid that.)

Comment: I’ve added an edit that hopefully gets things working for you.